# Interviewed for wrong position?

Tags: interviewing, internship

I recently applied for an internship at a large company which had several software developer positions with very different job descriptions. During my interview, the topics discussed matched perfectly with the description for one of the software developer positions *that I did not apply to*.

Needless to say, I am concerned because this was not the interview I had prepared for, and this position did not match well with my skillset. Is this something they may have done intentionally because the position I originally applied to has already been filled, or was it most likely someone's mistake? Should I let them know, and if I do is there any chance I'd get a second interview or some other recourse?

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you bring this up during or at the end of the interview?  That would have been the best time to bring it to their attention.

Comment: I didnt realize this was what had happened until after the interview

Comment: SDET? Please don't make people have to google in order to understand your jargon

Comment: HorusKol edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this something they may have done intentionally because the position I originally applied to has already been filled, or was it most likely someone's mistake?

Both are possible, although it's more likely it was the second thing.

> Should I let them know, and if I do is there any chance I'd get a second interview or some other recourse?

You should let them know if you really want this job and would like to clarify this situation. If you don't really want it, or have other options in mind, then don't waste your time on it and continue job-hunting.

If they will give you a second interview only they know. However, only by writing to them you will find out. If you feel like asking I suggest you write an email thanking for the interview and opportunity, and then asking for clarification on this possible misunderstanding.