# What to do if you got interviewed for the wrong position?

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search, follow-up

Today I had a job interview for a company that I really really want to work for.
However, the interview was about a different position than the one I applied for and so it didn't go as well (not really terrible either, just meh).

I was assuming that the company judged my profile as to be more fitting for the other role and since I also have some experience and find enjoyment in this area, I dint mention it during the interview that I was actually applying for a different position.

I could see that the interviewer was not entirely convinced with some of my answers but my know-how was still good enough to keep it running for 30 minutes.

So it was an OK interview, but I'm pretty sure that's not enough.

Would it be wise explain the situation in my follow-up email or should I shut up and hope for the best?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interviewed for wrong position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/128224/interviewed-for-wrong-position)

Comment: or https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/129861/interviewed-for-the-wrong-role?rq=1

Comment: I didnt realize this was what had happened until after the interview

Comment: In your mind, what would "the best" be by shutting up and hoping for the best? For them to discover the error and bring you back to interview for a different position? To be offered the wrong job?

Answer (score 6):

> I didn't mention it during the interview that I was actually applying for a different position.

Why not? **You should have done this right there**, so you don't waste your time in an interview for a position you don't want.

Guess that this is something you should keep in mind for future interviews.

> Would it be wise explain the situation in my follow-up email or should I shut up and hope for the best?

**If you hope to progress on this application, then by all means do ask and clarify this situation.** Thank them for the opportunity and politely ask for clarification.

If you don't clarify then you could be potentially wasting valuable time and effort from your part (and theirs) here. Ask.

Comment: I didnt realize this was what had happened until after the interview - my wor experience is still close enough to be considered relevant for such a position

Comment: @DT - If you feel it didn't go well, and you are likely not going to get the position that you interviewed for, then you have less to lose by saying you interviewed for the incorrect position than by saying nothing.